# Examples of non-adjoint equivalences

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-list

> What are some examples of equivalences whose canonical unit/counit fail to satisfy the triangle identities?

It is common knowledge that not all equivalences satisfy the [triangle identities](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/triangle+identities), but that any equivalence can be refined by swapping out its unit (or counit) with a different one to form an [adjoint equivalence](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/adjoint+equivalence) which does satisfy the triangles while leaving both functors intact, so all functors that are part of an equivalence are also part of an adjoint equivalence.

I'm curious about equivalences where the canonical unit and counit do not satisfy the triangle identities -- the meaning of canonical here is hopefully canonical, but to be more precise I mean that the unit and counit that are 'obvious' to write down do not satisfy the triangles and need to be modified using the refinement to adjoint equivalences to do so.

Comment: It deserves to be said that lots of examples of equivalences don't really come with a canonical unit / counit at all -- you just select one at random after showing that a functor is full, faithful, and essentially surjective.

Comment: If I give a non-adjoint equivalence that means that I've given an equivalence $F$ together with a nontrivial natural automorphism of $F$, right? That should suggest that this situation is uncommon, and might suggest where to look for an example...

Comment: @TimCampion I'm not sure about that.  In my experience a lot of equivalences are constructed by giving two functors and two natural isomorphisms.  And even when it's phrased as a proof of ff+eso, the proof of eso generally proceeds by constructing for each $y$ a specific $x$ and a specific isomorphism $fx\cong y$, which then canonically determines the structure of a functor on $y\mapsto x$ and a unit and counit for an adjoint equivalence.

Comment: I tend to agree with Mike — the proof that ff+eso iff antiparallel functors and natural isos provides a formula for getting a unit and counit out of a ff+eso functor, and as Mike points out if we have the eso part explicitly given we have an adjoint equivalence determined.

Comment: As implicit in previous comments: when you see "equivalent categories" as "having isomorphic skeletons", you hit the big problem of AC and "un-naturality".
Avoid it with "having isomorphic inflations": Freyd - Scedrof. I would look at the papers that introduced anafunctors;
I cannot acces them in this moment but I am quite confident that the examples they give might also answer this question.
(PS: category theory is the only place in mathematics where to define "natural transformation" you use a un-natural definition, and it works. Mostly, rare exceptions like this one).

Comment: Another way to look at the problem: http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf (Abstract and concrete categories) Remark 5.13 pag. 67 says that when a concrete equivalence from A to B exists, a concrete one from B to A might not exist.
Btw. I disagree with the statement "it makes little sense to say that they are concretely equivalent" (for a pair of concrete categories). In 1993 I defined and used a (symmetric) concept of concrete equivalence
more general than concrete isomorphism (and less general than the one in the book).

Comment: @MikeShulman The kind of example I have in mind is the inclusion functor from the category of cardinals with all functions between them, to the category of sets with all functions between them. One shows that this functor is fully faithful and essentially surjective. Unwinding the proof, sure one obtains an inverse functor, a unit, and a counit, but all of this data is dependent on a choice of well-ordering of each set. It's canonical with respect to some auxiliary data (isn't everything in math canonical with respect to auxiliary data?), sure, but in an important sense it's not canonical.

Comment: That's how I interpreted your comment, Tim, but maybe worth adding that even the "inverse" functor is selected "at random", and not just the unit/counit. A more typical example is where the inverse functor is produced by constructing (co)limits. Of course we can give a general construction of (e.g.) a colimit of sets, but there isn't anything particularly canonical about one construction over all the other ones.

Comment: @TimCampion It's true that there are artificial examples like that, but I don't think they arise very often in nature.

Comment: @ReidBarton However, once you fix a particular construction of a (co)limit to give the action on objects of the inverse functor, all the rest of the data is determined canonically.

Comment: That's true, but I don't see a philosophical justification for treating one construction of (co)limits as "canonical", while not likewise treating one construction of promoting an ess surj+ff functor to an equivalence as "canonical".

Comment: @ReidBarton Did I say something that sounded like claiming a particular construction of (co)limits was "canonical"?

Comment: One mathematical difference between constructions involving (co)limits and those like Tim's is that (co)limits can be constructed (albeit in many ways, with no one of them canonical) without the axiom of choice (or even the law of excluded middle).

Comment: @MikeShulman I misunderstood your intent as "once you fix a construction of (co)limits, the entire package of the equivalence is canonical", but now I see you meant something else. // In any case, examples constructed this way won't be examples of non-adjoint equivalences.

Comment: It also deserves to be said that a left adjoint equivalence will generally not be a right adjoint equivalence.

Comment: I think this discussion of what "canonical" means (where I _think_ the main point on which we're talking talking past each other is "what kind of auxiliary data is 'allowed'") is immaterial to the question at hand. Any theorem of the form "$F$ is an equivalence" will produce _some_ unit and counit, "canonical" or no. The question can be interpreted as "what are some examples where the unit and counit handed to us by the theorem are non-adjoint". Right?

Comment: Yes, canonicality is irrelevant to the original question!  But I do think a left adjoint equivalence is automatically also a right adjoint equivalence: just invert and exchange the unit and counit.

Comment: @MikeShulman (and Tim) : I think the situation Tim is referring to also happens quite often in $(\infty,1)$-categories, where specifying a functor is not as easy as just "objects and morphisms", and so very many equivalences are really only obtained by exhibiting an antecedent - of course, you could say what it does on objects and morphisms, but to specify the full inverse functor (*and* the isomorphisms) you just invoke the existence of inverses

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with a functor $U:{\mathcal A}\to{\mathcal X}$ that's full and faithful. Bypassing questions of Choice, it's also essentially surjective on objects in the sense that there is a *function* $F:{\mathsf ob}{\mathcal X}\to{\mathsf ob}{\mathcal A}$ along with an assignment of an isomporhism $\eta_X:X\to U F X$ to each object $X$.

From these data, for each morphism $f:X\to Y$ of $\mathcal X$, we define $F f:F X\to F Y$ as the unique $\mathcal A$-map such that
$$ \eta_X^{-1};f;\eta_Y = U(F f), $$
in other words such that $\eta$ is natural.   It is easy to check that $F$ preserves identity and composition.

It remains to define $\epsilon$.  For one of the triangle laws we require $U\epsilon_A=\eta_{U A}^{-1}$, which uniquely defines $\epsilon_A$ since $U$ is full and faithful. Naturality of $\epsilon$ follows from that of $\eta$.

The other triangle law is $\eta_{U A};U\epsilon_A={\mathsf id}$, for which it suffices that this hold with $U$ applied, since that's full and faithful.

By naturality of $\eta$ and the first triangle law, we have
$$ \eta_X;U F\eta_X; U\epsilon_{F X} = \eta_X;\eta_{U F X}; U\epsilon_{F X} = \eta_X $$
but $\eta_X$ is invertible an $U$ is full and faithful, so the other triangle law holds.

In other words, the obvious data for "full, faithful and essentially surjective on objects" yield an *adjoint* equivalence.

So what other kind of equivalence is there? If the isomorphism $\eta$ in "essential surjectivity" is to be natural, it can only be as above.  However, the other isomorphism $\epsilon'$ could come from somewhere else.  Nevertheless, $\eta_{U A};U\epsilon'_A$ is still a natural automorphism of $U A$, which must be $U$ applied to a natural isomorphism of $A$.

In other words, a non-adjoint equivalence is given by arbitrary natural isomorphisms applied to an adjoint equivalence.

This is a situation that can easily be realised with group isomorphisms, yielding the counterexample that was requested.

Comment: This is one of those "it is better to teach a man how to catch fish" answers.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: you're right, and the same applies to the question about diagrams that I wasted my time answering the other day. However, I was [*nerdsniped*](http://xkcd.com/356) and when I'd written the proof on paper I thought I might as well post it.

Comment: This is interesting, thank you; the question was intended as a ‘big list’ of examples (although per the discussion in comments ‘small list’ might be a better tag). Would you mind constructing one explicit example with group isomorphisms?

Comment: @AlecRhea: see Andrej's comment. Anyway, there is only one (pattern of) counterexample, not a "big list",

Comment: Yes, I am generally a proponent of just working it out myself, but I intended this question as a ‘big list’ as was indicated in the tags before you edited them. A big list of ‘work it out yourself’ answers is fine too, I’d just prefer at least one explicit example per answer. (I also don’t really know much group theory, I skipped it and went straight to category theory because it’s what I needed for my research)

Comment: How do you mean? Does your answer somehow preclude the possibility of ‘finding’ two antiparallel functors that form an equivalence which is not adjoint? (say Stone duality, which is adjoint but just as an example)

Comment: This answer is a nice writeup of nice material, but I don’t think it answers the question.  This shows how to construct examples artificially, and better, classifies them — but the question wants examples that are “canonical” (which I understand as meaning what I’d call something like “arising in nature”), which is a different and interesting question!